# JQuery validation of amount xxx.xx

Tags: jquery

I am working on JQuery and I have a requirement where user should not be allowed to enter value in thousands and if user enter value to should convert to decimal value.

```
1  -> 1.00
15 -> 15.00
100 -> 100.00
150.1 -> 150.10
999.10 -> 999.10
```

and application should throw error when user enters 1000, 10000 (6 chars are allowed in textbox, please help me with solution. Thank you!

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var num = parseFloat(string)

if (isNaN(num) || num >= 1000) {
    // Invalid input
}

numString = num.toFixed(2)
```